# How to handle exceptions from nested jobs?

Tags: sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a Sidekiq / ActiveJob class that looks like:

```
class ParentJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    ChildJobA.perform_now(user)
    ChildJobB.perform_now(user)
    ChildJobC.perform_now(user)
    ...
  rescue CustomError => e
    handle_error(e)
  end
end
```

The parent job is called via `ParentJob.perform_later(user)`.

The child jobs can raise a `CustomError`.  I thought that I could rescue those in the parent job – but my `rescue` block is never called.  It seems that the child job simply exits and control does not pass back to the parent.

Is there a way to rescue custom errors in the parent job or do I have to repeat the same error handler in every child job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it like normal Ruby code and remove ActiveJob from the picture:

```
ChildJobA.new.perform(user)
ChildJobB.new.perform(user)
ChildJobC.new.perform(user)
```

That should raise as normal.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!